# My code doesn't catch null arguments in c

Tags: c, error-handling

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long long input = strtoull(argv[1],NULL,10);
    if (argc < 2){
        puts("Need an argument");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why if I just enter the program name in cmd without an argument, this code is crashing?

EDIT:

New code still crashes instantly with null argument:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 2){
        puts("Too many arguments");
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc < 2){
        puts("Need an argument");
        return 0;
    }
    if(argv[1][0] == '-'){
        puts("Sorry, no negative numbers, try another input"); // no negatives
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `argv[1]` is `NULL` and it gets dereferenced? You need to check yourself, not expect library code to do it for you.

Comment: but if argv[1] is null, then argc is less than 2, it should catch it

Comment: @jacob The order of your lines is significant. You first do the potentially dangerous operation, then check later, which is kind of wrong.

Comment: I shouldn't need to check if argv exists because if it didn't then argc is less than 2. I don't access argv until after I've checked it

Comment: Here a few general tips: 1. Don't program in C if you cannot comfortably use a debugger on your system. 2. If you are desperate and try to program C without having a good debugger, use printf debugging. Here: ``for( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) puts(argv[i];`` to see what you have.

Comment: @Tom where am I accessing argv[1] before seeing if argc<2?

Comment: I edited it and then said that, read the OP tom.

Comment: I hadn't seen that you edited it.  The new version should say "Need an argument" if you don't provide one.  Not sure why it's crashing.  Did you remember to recompile it after making the change?

Comment: Stop making your question a moving target.  Half of the answers are meaningless now.

Comment: I think OP forgot to recompile after making the last change.  The problem should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Your are using `argv[1]` before you tested that it exits. So should check that `argc >= 2` before accessing `argv[1]`

Comment: Oh my god how did I not see that, I'm sorry for asking such a dumb question!

Comment: Because I checked argc which you haven't addressed which is the source of my confusion. Please comment somewhere else if all you aim to do is vent your frustrations onto others

Answer (score 1):

The command name is placed at index zero. You're referencing an index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand on exactly what you are typing into the command line to execute the program?  From the information given, it sounds like you are entering no command line parameters.  If this is the case, then you have a null reference exception in the following line:

```
unsigned long long input = strtoull(argv[1],NULL,10);
```

Possible modification would be the following:

```
if(argc >= 2)
{
     //Note argv is the second argument (zero indexing)
     unsigned long long input = strtoull(argv[1],NULL,10);
}
```

Basically, don't try and read argv[1] until you know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

As for your edited code, you are still trying to dereference argv[1] outside of any control statements.  This will cause your code to crash.  Make sure there IS an argv[1] before you attempt to use it.

```
if(argc > 2)
{
     if(argv[1]......)
}
```